# How to get odoo 8 without all business modules stuffs?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to deeply understand how ODOO work so I need to install just ODOO core the basic that power the machinery without all business modules stuff like accountant, HR, Sale and all that, just a clean and lightweight ( not the 300MB size package) installation that work, so I can login and log out and build my own HR module if I want (this is not my aim of course). So in order to that can you guys help me figure out which module compose the core of ODOO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to do this installation on your local machine by downloading and installing all the dependencies , you just need to write this command:

```
./odoo.py -d DBNAME --db-filter DBNAME
```

### Parameters:

-d         : It will create the database with DBNAME
--db-filter: It will choose this newly created database to login.

This will only install the "base" module which you are quoting here as "core".

No other module like sale or account will be installed by itself.

However, if you wish to install new module with command then :

```
./odoo.py -d DBNAME --db-filter DBNAME -i MODULENAME
```

Or you can install it via "Apps" menu as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try their demo instance at: https://demo.odoo.com/
Also, check their official [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/setup/install.html). Here you have everything related to the installations.